# Is ROS just a simulator on Ubuntu?

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Question 1:
Is ROS just a simulator on Ubuntu?

Question 2:
Is ROS a Linux plus tools(e.g. OpenCV) running inside a REAL robot? If yes, how to burn ROS into a REAL robot? Where is the development Kit?(e.g. raspberry pi)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246219/is-ros-just-a-simulator-on-ubuntu?/) by [U032132](https://answers.ros.org/users/28313/u032132/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-23

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-23**:
[wiki/ROS/Introduction](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Introduction), [ros.org/about-ros](http://www.ros.org/about-ros/), [wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System), [What is ROS exactly?](http://answers.ros.org/question/12230), ...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-23**:
..., [ROS 101: Intro to the Robot Operating System](http://robohub.org/ros-101-intro-to-the-robot-operating-system/), [Quora - What is ROS?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-ROS)?

All of these pages are not clear? Could you please elaborate what it is that you don't get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1.ROS is not a simulator.it is robot development frame.you can use any hardware to build a robot,every hardware can be communication through roscore/rosmaster.
2.You can use a min_x86 board ，arm board，raspberry pi.lt is installed ros system,it is a controller.the motors or sensors is accessed to controller,then the robot can be controlled.
I hope it is helpful.

---

Originally posted by [Yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/20790/yang/) with karma: 36 on 2016-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0